# 'AggsProxy' object is not callable error on Python when trying to access ES aggregations

Tags: python, elasticsearch, bucket, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to query elasticsearch from pyton. What I want to do is first search the keyword and then I want to count of the each keyword after the match query.Here's my code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search, Q, A
from elasticsearch_dsl.query import Match
import pandas as pd #for analyzing the data 
#Created a client here
print("keyword?)
keyword= input()
q = (Q("match", myfield=keyword))
a = A("terms", field="myfield")
s = Search(using=client, index="myindex").query(q)
s.aggs(a)
response=s.execute()
bucket_results = response.aggregations.bucket
for key, value in bucket_results.items():
     print(key, value)
```

Match query works just fine but when I tried to add aggregations part I get this error:
s.aggs(a)
TypeError: 'AggsProxy' object is not callable **bucket_results = response.aggregations.bucket()** instead of attribute

I also tried to access aggregations with method **bucket_results = response.aggregations.bucket()** instead of attribute but that doesn't seem to work also. What should I do? Why this error occurred?

p.s: I am connected to a remote server. Is it possible that I am not allowed to do aggs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at https://www.lewuathe.com/elasticsearch-aggregation-with-python-dsl.html

from elasticsearch_dsl import Search, Q, A

```
search_query = Search(using=client, index=index_name)
count = A("terms", field="myfield")
search_query.aggs.bucket("count", count)
response = search_query.execute()
```